# how to access an AR class instance from a component?

Tags: php, yii, rbac

The business rule set is,

```
return isset($params["profile"]) && $params["profile"]->isUserinRole("manager");
```

I am displaying a User Menu using the components, now in this component view I want the options that only the 'manager' can see and apply.

I tried doing this and it doesn't work

```
Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('manager', array('profile'=>Profile::model())))
```

Please correct me, thanks.

Comment: What does your `Profile` model look like? Please show the `checkAccess` function

Comment: @PrabowoMurti Here is the profile model, http://codepad.org/F0dtHwLN , read about checkAccess here, http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth#using-business-rules